# Produce a dummy string N characters long with java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are numerous ways to do this, but using Java 8 streams (likely IntStream), how can I produce a dummy string that is N characters long?

I've seen examples using IntStream.range(), and the various aggregator functions (sum, average), but I don't see a way to do this.

My first random guess looks like this:

```
IntStream.range(1, 110).map(i -> "x").collect(Collectors.joining());
```

But that's wrong in a couple of different ways.

Comment: If it looks wrong for you, just write `StringStream` =)

Comment: I would use guava for this with `Strings#repeat`

Comment: `Stream.generate(() -> "x").limit(n).collect(joining())`

Comment: "But that's wrong in a couple of different ways." - Why?

Comment: I think that the fastest way, would be to do a `Array.fill` here, to produce a `char[]` and than simply do `new String(char[])`...

Comment: @shmosel that would suck in parallel though

Comment: @Eugene Most code sucks in parallel. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: @shmosel something `InstStream` or `Array` band that can be splitter better would be much more suited for parallel processing, nothing more

Comment: @Eugene What processing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `mapToObj()` and not `map()` as you actually use an `IntStream` and `IntStream.map()` takes as parameter an `IntUnaryOperator`, that is an (int->int) function.

**For same character dummy (for example "x")**  :

```
collect = IntStream.range(1, 110)
                   .mapToObj(i ->"x")
                   .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**Form random dummy :**

You could use [`Random.ints(long streamSize, int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-).

> Returns a stream producing the given streamSize number of pseudorandom
>   int values, each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound
>   (exclusive).

To generate a String containing 10 random characters between the 65 and 100 ASCII code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String collect = new Random().ints(10, 65, 101)
                                 .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
                                 .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(collect);

}
```

Comment: it's not random...

Comment: @Eugene Can you detail ?

Comment: the Op wants `AAAAAA`.... not `AGCVT`

Comment: @Eugene  Thanks !

Comment: oh wow! :) really? this is what OP was missing?

Comment: you can also use `mapToObj(Character::toString)` in the 2nd example

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use a `Stream` for this, you can utilize `Stream#generate`, and limit it to `n` characters:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "x").limit(110).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually almost there:

```
String s = IntStream.range(40, 110)
                    .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char)i))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(s);
```

Produces:

```
()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklm
```

If you want random ordering, with `N = 60` for instance:

```
Random r = new Random();    

IntStream.generate(() -> 40 + r.nextInt(70))
         .limit(60)
         .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char)i))
         .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Produces

```
Z>fA+5OY@:HfP;(L:^WKDU21T(*1//@V,F9O-SA2;+),A+V/mLjm<eaE56CH
```